# Bitmaps lose transparency when downloaded with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide, bitmapimage

I am trying to download a bitmap image in an android app using the Glide library (version 4), but when I do that the transparency of the image is lost and it is replaced by a white background.
I tried using the commands:

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url).into(imageView);
```

and

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).apply( new RequestOptions().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888).encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)).into(imageView);
```

However nothing seems to work.

The image url is: https://s151.convertio.me/p/HwxwbAP4nbAyKsEmdn7ORw/1dc5e4a91d3de94ef6c5fcd51b0fb79d/yellow_circle_1.bmp

And here are some screenshots of the app:
This is how it should look.
[image: This is how it should look.] (It looks like that when I use a png image, the red background is the ImageView's background and the image background is transparent.)

This is how it looks with a bitmap
[image: This is how it looks with a bitmap] (The transparent background became white.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146685/android-imageview-shows-greenish-image

Comment: Try it with a PNG instead of a BMP.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried it with a png (it is the first image link), however I need to be able to do that with a bitmap too.

Comment: You are assuming that Android supports an alpha channel when decoding BMP images. Since alpha channel support in BMP seems weak, I would not be surprised if Android does not support it. Run a test with using `BitmapFactory` directly, skipping Glide -- if the BMP "loses" transparency, then Android simply does not support it for that file format.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alpha channel in BMP format, as far as I know
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: If you download the image manually, you can see that the background is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Glide.with(context).load(dataModel.getImgurl())
               .thumbnail(0.5f)
               .fitCenter()
               .centerCrop()
               .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
               .into(imageView);
```

Comment: i am not able to acess your image url

Comment: The image url is: [link](https://s151.convertio.me/p/HwxwbAP4nbAyKsEmdn7ORw/1dc5e4a91d3de94ef6c5fcd51b0fb79d/yellow_circle_1.bmp)
It is posted in the question too.