# Why images are displayed with light grey background, when it has white android?

Tags: android, image, background, imageview, android-glide

[image]

When I am displaying image in `ImageView` using `Glide`, grey color is added in background.I have tried setting background color to transparent and  even white in ImageView in my xml file..
But It is still not working..It is happening with every image I display in various activities.
Below is the screenshot of same image displayed in iPhone and Android Oreo.
Below is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bklayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="28dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/bkbutton"
             android:layout_width="35dp"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"/>
         </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewPager"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
         </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/new_grey">
         </View>


        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product Name: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
                <com.example.unsan.grouponebuy.helpers.ExpandableTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:id="@+id/desc"/>
             </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/fav"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite_grey_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/favtext"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/favorite"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_dark" />

          </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/origprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/specification" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/specification"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/origin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/origin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/replacement_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_box_green_24dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/replacement_policy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/prodCartLayout">
    <View

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"></View>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/carticonbutton"
            android:src="@drawable/cart_bl" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></View>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/carttext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/add_to_cart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/outOfStock"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:id="@+id/soldout_text"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/prodSelectedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/new_grey"></View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/carticonbutton2"
                android:src="@drawable/cart_bl" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sub_quantity"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_quantity"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_on" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_detail);
        backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bkbutton);
        cartImageButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.carticonbutton);
        cartButton2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.carticonbutton2);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        productNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        originText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.origin);
        specText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.specification);
        favText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.favtext);
        favImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fav);
        priceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        soldOutText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soldout_text);
        quantityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        addButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_quantity);
        subButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sub_quantity);
        originalPriceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.origprice);
        descriptionText = (ExpandableTextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
        cartLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.prodCartLayout);
        productSelectedLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.prodSelectedLayout);
        cartAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.carttext);
        replacementLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.replacement_layout);
        listViews = new ArrayList<>();
        indicator = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        globalProvider = GlobalProvider.getGlobalProviderInstance(getApplicationContext());
        buyNumView = new CircleBadgeView(this, cartButton2);
        buyNumView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        buyNumView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        numBadge = new CircleBadgeView(this, cartImageButton);
        numBadge.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        //cycleTextViewExpansion(descriptionText);
        // expandCollapsedByMaxLines(descriptionText);

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("productupdated", product);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        product = (Product) intent.getSerializableExtra("product");


        List<String> imgList = product.getImageDisplay();
        if (Constants.getLanguage(this).equals("english")) {

            String origin = product.getOriginEn();


            productNameText.setText(product.getNameEn());
            originText.setText(origin);
            ;
            specText.setText(product.getSpecificationEn());
            if (product.getDescriptionEn() != null) {
                descriptionText.setText(product.getDescriptionEn());
            }
        } else {
            productNameText.setText(product.getNameCh());
            originText.setText(product.getOriginCh());
            specText.setText(product.getSpecificationCh());
            if (product.getDescriptionCh() != null) {
                descriptionText.setText(product.getDescriptionCh());
            }
        }

        boolean prodSelected = false;


        priceText.setText("$ " + product.getPrice());
        listViews.clear();


        indicator.removeAllViews();

        if (imgList.size() > 0)

        {
            for (int a = 0; a < imgList.size(); a++) {
                ViewGroup pager = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.viewpager_image, null);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) pager.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerimg);
               /* if (a == 0) {

                        imageView.setTransitionName(imgTransitionName);

                }
                */
                Glide.with(ProductDetailActivity.this).load(Constants.baseUrlStr + imgList.get(a)).override(500, 500).centerCrop().into(imageView);
                listViews.add(pager);


            }
            productDetailViewPagerAdapter = new ProductDetailViewPagerAdapter(listViews, this);
            viewPager.setAdapter(productDetailViewPagerAdapter);


            if (imgList.size() > 1) {
                for (int a = 0; a < imgList.size(); a++) {
                    if (a == 0) {
                        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15, 15);
                        imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_dot);
                        indicator.addView(imgView);


                    } else {
                        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15, 15);
                        lp.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
                        imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_dot);
                        // imgs.add(img);
                        indicator.addView(imgView);


                    }
                }
            } else {

                ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                        (15, 15);
                //lp.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
                img.setLayoutParams(lp);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_dot);
                //imgs.add(img);
                indicator.addView(img);

            }
        }


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                for (int i = 0; i < indicator.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (i == position) {
                        ((ImageView) indicator.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_dot);

                    } else {
                        ((ImageView) indicator.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.default_dot);
                    }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Below is theme of my app:

```
    <resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>


        </style>
        <style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
            <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        </style>

</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the image itself has the grayish background. Can you post the image of pumpkin in your question, please?

Comment: @JinsLukose Hmm, There is no other way the image to appear like that in Glide, is it?

Comment: @user3792429 you are right, it is white, Can you post your code of both java and xml as **Jay** suggested, please?

Comment: is there any way to achieve the opposite? adding a grey background to the product images which have a white background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found a solution..It was Glide's issue
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/853
Using DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE and DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888 had resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

Whichever parent layout you have placed your `ImageView` such as `<LinearLayout>` or `<RelativeLayout>` or `<ConstraintLayout>`, they all have a Default color code as `#FAFAFA` which is not exactly *White* and that one of the possible reason that

White's color code as you might already know is `#FFFFFF`.

So your answer lies in your layout, make the background color of your parent layout in which your `ImageView` resides as *White* `#FFFFFF` as shown below:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bklayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="28dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bkbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
   </LinearLayout>
```

---

**UPDATE:** Add the below line in your `Glide` as described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32185010/9763253)

```
.dontTransform()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
```

Try it, I hope this is the problem.